# Why are there two versions of SDK Manager? Which one to use?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager

I've installed (unzipped) the Android [command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#cmdline-tools) package on Linux, and I've set these environment vars into my `.bashrc` file:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Programs/Android
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/lib:$PATH
```

The version displayed for `sdkmanager` is:

```
$ sdkmanager --version
    4.0.1
```

With that manager I've installed other packages:

```
$ sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" "build-tools;29.0.3"
$ sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

And some directories were created under `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, among them is `tools` directory, with similar structure to `cmdline-tools/tools` directory but more files. Both `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin` and `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin` own the `sdkmanager` file, and every file displays a different version:

```
$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager   ==> 4.0.1
$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager                 ==> 26.1.1
```

I've not modified my initial environment vars, and been working fine with my created emulators until recently started to receive one message in my terminal (when launching my emulator) containing the following text:

```
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio
```

That message is showed for first time only, for next re-launches it is not until certain period of time after. It does not interfere when launch my emulator and not decrement its performance.

According to [this release note](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html), SDK Tools package is deprecated (the last version was `26.1.1`), and it asks to use the new command-line tools package.

[Documentation for command-line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) package does not mention about current version for this package, [sub-section Android SDK Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/#tools-sdk) says it should be located in `android_sdk/cmdline-tools/version/bin/`, so which `version`? It is not mentioned in [the page](https://developer.android.com/studio#cmdline-tools) where zipped file is downloaded.

So why there two versions for `sdkmanager` file in my system? Which one to use? Is the message for outdated emulator related to these two files?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that version `4.0.1` was installed first, I could only speculate as to why the deprecated version was also installed. I suspect that either one of your installed packages had the old version as a requirement or at the time of installation the `cmdline-tools;latest` had not yet been pointed to `4.0.1` version. If it's truly important, the only way I can think of to check would be to repeat the process and then install the packages one at a time to help narrow it down.

With regards to your other question, unless there is some obselete functionality needed, it is typically good practice to drop deprecated Software. As such I think that in this situation using the `cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager`, that is version `4.0.1`, would be the prudent move.

I'm not sure about the message regarding the outdated emulator.